# wget for Windows - using --post-data with quotes

Tags: post, wget

I'm using wget for Windows and I want to specify a `--post-data` filter (and avoid using a `--post-file` filter) but I'm struggling to get it to work. It might be because there are strings within double quote marks like this :

```
wget "http://www.somesite.com/wfs" --header="Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8"
--user=username --password=password --no-check-certificate
--post-data="big long string with "quotes" in it" --output-document=C:\Test.xml
```

Has anyone else successfully got `--post-data` to work in wget for Windows? Am I missing something?

Cheers

Andy

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can escape the quotes in your big long string by prefixing them with `\` e.g.

```
--post-data="big long string with \"quotes\" in it"
```

Answer (score 3):

Also using double quotes inside the quotes:

```
--post-data="big long string with ""quotes"" in it"
```