# How to use wget to post a html form?

Tags: html, wget

I have a form like this located at http://www.sms-online.web.id:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<body>

    <form method="post" enctype="multipart-form-data" name="my_form" onsubmit="clearTextBoxCounter()" action="http://www.sms-online.web.id/kirim" >

      <input type=hidden name=teks value=><center><b>KIRIM SMS GRATIS</b></center><br><br>
    Nomer:<br />
      <input type="text" maxlength="20" name="Phonenumbers" value="08888888"/>
      <br />

    <br />
    Isi:<br />
    <textarea rows="5" cols="50" onKeyPress=check_length(this.form); onKeyDown=check_length(this.form); name=Text >
    Content of my sms
    </textarea>
    <br />

    <input id="saveForm" class="btTxt" type="submit" value="KIRIM" name="TOMBOL" />

    </body>
    </html>
```

I would like to post to that form and then submit it, how do I use wget to do the job? I've read about `wget --post-data xxx` but I still don't know what I should type in in the terminal, based on that html file, should I type in like this? (I'm really not sure it'll work) `wget --post-data value=08585858 textarea="Content of my sms" http://www.sms-online.web.id`

Answer (score 9):

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8599760/variables-in-wget-post-data) SO question:

```
wget --post-data="value=08585858&textarea=\"Content of sms\"" <url>
```

Also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1237433/wget-for-windows-using-post-data-with-quotes).